# How to add JS variable in ruby code?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery

I have JS function with ajax where is following url:

```
var company_count = COMPANIES_PER_PAGE;

....

url: '<%=j companies_path(start: ' + company_count + ', f: params[:f]) %>',
....
company_count += COMPANIES_PER_PAGE;
```

but this gives me in script:

```
url: '/companies?f=k&amp;start=company_count',
```

And I want to get for ex:

```
url: '/companies?f=k&start=30',
```

Whole script

```
  <script>
    var COMPANIES_PER_PAGE = <%= @companies_per_page %>;
    var company_count = COMPANIES_PER_PAGE;

    $(document).ready( function(){
      checkScroll();
    });

    function checkScroll() {
      if (nearBottomOfPage()) {
        $('#loading_more_'+(company_count-COMPANIES_PER_PAGE)).fadeTo(200, 1);
        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: '<%=j companies_path(start: company_count, f: params[:f]) %>',
           dataType: "script"
         });
        company_count += COMPANIES_PER_PAGE;
      } else {
        setTimeout(checkScroll, 250);
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Js variables should be added as data attributes in the DOM. Then your js code can take them from here. In ajax, send JSON back to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the data attribute of $.ajax()? It allows you to attach all your JS variables, plus your Ruby-generated ones...

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: '<%=j companies_path %>',
       data: { start: "<%= params[:f] %>", start: company_count },
       dataType: "script"
});
```

Comment: I get an error with ``f: "<%=params[:f] %>"`` I used ``url: '<%=j companies_path(f: params[:f]) %>'``